# Primefaces Pie chart legend overflows graph area

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1 and JSF 2.2.4. On my application I have a functionality that renders a graph based on a result of a search. The problem is when the search returns many itens my graph legend overflows the graph area here is the image:

[image]

I've looked into the documentation and couldn't find anything about the legend size or something else that could solve my problem.

There is nothing wrong with the code so I think that there is no need to add it. If you think otherwise please tell me.

Comment: Did you try to increase the size of the chart? Or seeif a multi-column legend plugin exists? Or…

Comment: @Kukeltje The size of the graph is already on the max size of the screen that was given as a requirement. Nothing on the official documentation about multi-column legend. I even posted it on the official Primefaces forum but nothing so far. Though I didn't look for third-part plugin. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solve my problem. I had to upgrade the primefaces version to 5.2 (I was using 5.1) and since this version there are new attributes do be setted on managed bean.

What I did to the legend work properly as I wanted was two things:

On the managed bean method that process the graph I added the line:

```
chartModel.setLegendCols(4);
```

And on the xhtml file I increased the graph size adding the style attribute size:

```
 <p:chart type="pie" 
          model="#{chartMBean.chartModel}"
          style="width:1200px; height:600px"/>
```

And voila:

[image]